MediaElement isn't playing video
MediaElement isn't working, I've copied and pasted the code from many examples and tried to start, but the element wasn't loaded, just white screen
the code:
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Source="http://hubblesource.stsci.edu/sources/video/clips/details/images/hst_1.mpg" />
</Grid>

I've tried other variations of the code, but still getting the same result.
It is the output


@Charles_Henington is right.
Basically, MediaElement is just a region where WMP outputs video. This is also related to the restriction that the video must be in an external file, since this is the only way WMP can get it. Therefore, first of all, check whether WMP can play this file on your system.

It appears that media element uses WMP ActiveX. It should be able to play anything that WMP can but it depends on what kind of Media Foundation codecs are installed on the PC. If we take a look at Media Foundation supported media formats
it doesn't seem to support mpg files from what I can tell but does support m4v, avi, wmv, mov and mp4 video formats.

You are right. I gave a comment to the question.

I've tried to use mp4 and wmv, tried to encode the video file with all the options, but result the same.

How are you converting? ffmpeg? ffmpeg -i $input.mpg -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -crf 20 -preset:v veryslow $output.mp4
